# What is the type of HttpRequest and HttpEvent in interceptor using angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular and implementing interceptor in angular project. In the below code, type for HttpRequest and HttpEvent is specified as any. But I need to specify the proper type for HttpRequest and HttpEvent. Can anyone help me in this

```
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `unknown` instead of `any`. This is because the type is unknown at compile time, and can never be known really.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>>
```

Answer (score -2):

I am curios, on why you need to specify the "proper type"?

The actual Definition of HttpRequest and HttpEvent can be seen
here https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequestand here https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpEvent

As we can see in the Docs, the type is `T`, which means it is a Generic Type.
It represents the actual Data Type you want to fetch.

If you want to load a List of Users, the Request would be `HttpRequest<User[]>`. Users in this Context is defined in your project and not in Angular itself.

**What is a Generic Type?**

A Generic Type is a way of telling TypeScript that the actual Type of this will be defined at Runtime, rather than at Compile Time.

**Compile Time vs Runtime**

In Essence, everything you do until you build your APP is the Compile Time.
You can imagine a Colleague looking at your Code and spotting Errors/ Type mismatches etc.

Runtime on the other Hand is self-explanatory. This is when you actually run your Application, i.e. if you navigate there in a Browser.

At this Point, there cannot be any Instance of any Generic Type with type `T`. `T` must be replaced with something defined, i.e. `number, string, etc.`
or any User Defined Model.

**Why is the type `any` then?**

All Interceptors implement the same Interface and Angular actually does use the an Interceptor to perform the actual communication which the server.
(https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpBackend)

And as written, `T` stands for the actual Data retrieving from the Server. There is no way, that the Angular Dev-Team can know what that will be.

That is why you have the `any` type there.

**Could you define the specific Type in the Interceptor?**

In Theory, yes.

Does it work? I actually don't know.

Interceptor are chained, meaning if there are multiple of them, all will be called in the order of them being provided.
If you do change `any` to another type, this might break in Runtime.
Feel free to try it though, might be a good Learning experience.

**Should you do it?**

Probably not.

Interceptors are used to perform various implicit tasks like Logging,
setting the Auth-Header etc. The Tasks should not depend on the type of the Response.